# remove breadcrumbs from checkout page storefront theme woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, breadcrumbs, storefront

I have tried to remove the breadcrumbs from just the 'checkout' page on woocommerce with the Storefront theme. I have looked at numerous ways on here and else where but none seem to work. Any suggestions woul dbe appreciated.

Here is a couple of different codes I have tried. Where am I going wrong?

```
add_action( 'init', 'wc_remove_storefront_breadcrumbs');
function wc_remove_storefront_breadcrumbs() {
if (is_page('checkout')){
  remove_action( 'storefront_before_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 10 );
}
}
```

```
 add_action( 'init', 'wc_remove_storefront_breadcrumbs');

function wc_remove_storefront_breadcrumbs() {
if (is_checkout()){
  remove_action( 'storefront_before_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 10 );
}
}
```

Comment: FYI I am inserting the codes into my child theme function.php

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following, as maybe 'init' is the wrong hook to use there:

```
add_action( 'storefront_before_content', 'bbloomer_remove_storefront_breadcrumbs_checkout', 1 );

function bbloomer_remove_storefront_breadcrumbs_checkout() {
   if ( is_checkout() ) {
      remove_action( 'storefront_before_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 10 );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @businessbloomer that worked! It's odd that 'init' did not work as that is what they state on the woocommerce docs site >https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/customise-the-woocommerce-breadcrumb/

Comment: Cool, glad to know! Please mark the answer as completed - thank you!